# Firebase query in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I have an structure like this in "/users"

```
{
 "aaa@aaa-com":{
     "email":"aaa@aaa.com",
     "name": "Joseph",
 },
 "asd@asd-com": {
     "email": "asd@asd.com",
     "name": "Erik"
 }
}
```

I made a query to access the child that has the email "aaa@aaa.com" :

```
    usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue("aaa@aaa.com") .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("user exists")

        } else if !snapshot.exists(){
            print("user doesn't exists")


        }
```

If I print(snapshot) I get the console output in xcode:

```
Snap (users) {
    "aaa@aaa-com" =     {
         email = "aaa@aaa.com";
         name = "Joseph";
     };
 }
```

I'm trying to find some way to get the name of the user after doing this query, but I didn't find the way to do it.
I tried with:

```
    print(snapshot.value.objectForKey("name"))
    print(snapshot.value.valueForKey("name"))
```

but I get nil in both.

Do you guys know how to get the name value?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried instead of quering `("aaa@aaa-com")`  instead of `("aaa@aaa.com")`? I think that's why is not finding it

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, and there are a ton of other resources out there. Hopefully this will help if you haven't gotten there already.

The easiest way is to cast `snapshot.value` to type `[String: AnyObject]`. Then, you can access the inner nodes.

```
usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("email")
        .queryEqualToValue("aaa@aaa.com")
        .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    // if you know that your value will not be nil, then you can unwrap like below
    //let foo = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

    if let foo = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let name = foo["name"] as? String
        let email = foo["email"] as? String
    }

}
```

**Swift 3**

```
usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email")
        .queryEqual(toValue: "aaa@aaa.com")
        .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    // if you know that your value will not be nil, then you can unwrap like below
    //let foo = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

    if let foo = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let name = foo["name"] as? String
        let email = foo["email"] as? String
    }

}
```

Given your position in the JSON tree because of your query, the above should work for you.

If you were one level up in the tree at the `users` node, and wanted to get all values, you could access like this:

```
usersRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    let users: [User] = []

    for item in snapshot.children {

        if let foo = item.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = User()

            user.name = foo["name"] as? String
            user.email = foo["email"] as? String

            users.append(user)
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to convert the snapshot into a NSDictionary like this

```
snap.value! as! NSDictionary
```

make sure that the snapshot isn´t nil

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://YOUR-URL.firebaseio.com/");
ref.orderByChild("location").equalTo("United States").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  document.write(snapshot.key());
console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

Replace `location` with `email`, or `name`, and `United Sates` with a parameter that you are searching for.

BTW, `document.write(snapshot.key())` will actually print the `snapshot` onto the `HTML` webpage instead of just in the console!